# How to plot several histograms in 3D

Tags: r, plot

I have a matrix, of which I am interested in seeing the histogram of each of its columns. I know i can do:

```
plot(hist(matrix[,1]))
plot(hist(matrix[,2]))
...
```

But the matix is too big to see them one by one.
Is there any way to view all histograms together in 3D? with one of the axes indicating the column of the matrix?

Here is an example of what I would get:

[image]

Here is a sample of the matrix:

```
structure(c(NA, NA, 1.31465157083122, 2.45193573457435, 0.199286884102187, 
-0.582004580221445, -0.913392457024085, 0.658326559365533, NA, 
2.21197511820371, 2.36579731400639, -0.000510082269577106, 0.393059607124003, 
-1.36455847501863, -0.542487903412945, NA, -0.261258769731502, 
0.04148453760142, -1.42070452577314, 0.691542553151913, 1.47987552505958, 
0.0224975403992187, NA, 1.56974507446696, 1.90249933525468, -0.437021545814293, 
0.454737374592012, -1.0878614529509, 0.627186393203703, NA, 0.145851439728549, 
0.40936131652147, -0.153723085968811, 0.328905938807818, -1.71717138316059, 
-0.689153933391654, NA, 0.995053570477659, 0.52437929844123, 
-0.575674543054854, 0.270445880527806, 0.687370627535606, -0.093161291192605, 
NA, -0.236497317032018, -1.75414127403493, 0.492217604070983, 
0.746003941151324, -1.4148437700946), .Dim = c(7L, 7L))
```

Comment: Why not an overlayed histogram with transparency?  I don't see how the 3D helps, it actually obscures and hides the histogram shape on the back side.

Comment: The image is just for reference, and the matrix is really big, the length of its columns it's about 7000. Still I do not plan to plot all histograms but I think even with 100 transparencies would be difficult to see. I can try but I don't know how to do that either

Comment: How about using the facets, hmmm the answer was just deleted.  You said you have to reproduce a graph, can you upload the graph you need to reproduce?

Comment: looks very similar to this: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOz6r.png)   This graph is made with hist3d function but i don't know how to use for my case

Comment: Is reproducing this graph a necessity? Again unless you can rotate the graph the backside is obscured. You should consider a heatmap instead where height is transformed to a color gradient, much like the linked graph but flattened.

Comment: Yes, i have think on the heatmap. hist3d() of the Plot3d package allows me to rotate the view, but i still not understand how to use it to plot the histograms of each column of my matrix.

Comment: Subset your matrix, you only need say 10x10 to illustrate the concept. Edit and paste the output of `dput(your_matrix[1:10,1:10])` into your question.

Comment: The edit is done

Comment: Please paste exactly the output of `dput(sample_matrix[1:7,1:7])`, where `sample_matrix` is the subset you used.  This puts your data in a format that we can just copy/paste on our end.

Comment: something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Given `sample_matrix`:

```
sample_matrix <- structure(c(NA, NA, 1.31465157083122, 2.45193573457435, 0.199286884102187, -0.582004580221445, -0.913392457024085, 0.658326559365533, NA, 2.21197511820371, 2.36579731400639, -0.000510082269577106, 0.393059607124003, -1.36455847501863, -0.542487903412945, NA, -0.261258769731502, 0.04148453760142, -1.42070452577314, 0.691542553151913, 1.47987552505958, 0.0224975403992187, NA, 1.56974507446696, 1.90249933525468, -0.437021545814293, 0.454737374592012, -1.0878614529509, 0.627186393203703, NA, 0.145851439728549, 0.40936131652147, -0.153723085968811, 0.328905938807818, -1.71717138316059, -0.689153933391654, NA, 0.995053570477659, 0.52437929844123, -0.575674543054854, 0.270445880527806, 0.687370627535606, -0.093161291192605, NA, -0.236497317032018, -1.75414127403493, 0.492217604070983, 0.746003941151324, -1.4148437700946), .Dim = c(7L, 7L))

rownames(sample_matrix) <- paste("Row", 1:nrow(sample_matrix))
colnames(sample_matrix) <- paste("Col", 1:ncol(sample_matrix))
```

**Calculating histogram per column**

Note for the single case of computing `hist`, compare column 1 with column 5, `$counts` and `$breaks` return different length and ranges:

```
Col1_hist <- hist(sample_matrix[, 1])
Col1_hist$counts
# [1] 2 1 1 1
Col1_hist$breaks
# [1] -1  0  1  2  3

Col5_hist <- hist(sample_matrix[, 5])
Col5_hist$counts
# [1] 1 0 0 1 3 1
Col5_hist$breaks
# [1] -2.0 -1.5 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0
```

Therefore, need to define common histogram breaks across all columns, we can do this by finding the min and max of all data and decide on binwidth that we use consistently across all histograms.

```
# find min and max of data
hist_min <- floor(min(sample_matrix, na.rm=T))
hist_max <- ceiling(max(sample_matrix, na.rm=T))

# Define common breaks across columns, select binwidth of 1
binwidth <- 1
hist_breaks <- seq(from=hist_min-binwidth/2, to=hist_max+binwidth/2, by=binwidth)

hist_breaks
# [1] -2.5 -1.5 -0.5  0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5
```

Now we can return consistent histograms across all columns in each single case.

```
Col1_hist <- hist(sample_matrix[, 1], breaks=hist_breaks)
Col1_hist$counts
# [1] 0 2 1 1 1 0
Col1_hist$breaks
# [1] -2.5 -1.5 -0.5  0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5

Col5_hist <- hist(sample_matrix[, 5], breaks=hist_breaks)
Col5_hist$counts
# [1] 1 0 4 1 0 0
Col5_hist$breaks
# [1] -2.5 -1.5 -0.5  0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5
```

Now we calculate histograms for each column using `apply`, where rows represent bins centered at `-2,-1,0,1,2,3`:

```
# Use apply to iterate our hist function across columns, and grab the counts column
sample_matrix_hist <- apply(sample_matrix, 2, function(x) hist(x, breaks=hist_breaks)$counts)
# Rownames define the bins of the histogram
rownames(sample_matrix_hist) <- seq(from=hist_min, to=hist_max, by=binwidth)

sample_matrix_hist
#        Col 1 Col 2 Col 3 Col 4 Col 5 Col 6 Col 7
# -2     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
# -1     2     1     2     1     0     2     1
# 0      1     2     2     3     4     1     3
# 1      1     1     2     0     1     3     1
# 2      1     2     0     2     0     0     0
# 3      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

**Plotting**

We will use `RColorBrewer` `Spectral` palette for illustration in the different plot options.

Plot using `hist3D` from `plot3D` package:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plot3D)
# z is the sample_matrix_hist values, x are the histogram bins, y are the columns of sample_matrix, z is frequency
hist3D(z=t(sample_matrix_hist), y=as.numeric(rownames(sample_matrix_hist)), x=1:ncol(sample_matrix_hist),
   theta=40, phi=40, label=TRUE, ticktype="detailed", 
   ylab="bin", xlab="columns", zlab="frequency", 
   col=rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"))(75)))
```

See `?hist3D` for further plot specifications

[image]

Here is 3D plot color coded by column. We need to create a coloring variable map first.

```
# Create coloring variable map
hist3D_colvar <- matrix(rep(seq(ncol(sample_matrix_hist)), each=nrow(sample_matrix_hist)), nrow=ncol(sample_matrix_hist), ncol=nrow(sample_matrix_hist), byrow = T)
hist3D(z=t(sample_matrix_hist), y=as.numeric(rownames(sample_matrix_hist)), x=1:ncol(sample_matrix_hist),
       theta=40, phi=40, label=TRUE, ticktype="detailed", 
       ylab="bin", xlab="columns", zlab="frequency", 
       colvar=hist3D_colvar, lighting=TRUE)
```

[image]

Alternatively, use a heatmap, here I use `heatmap.2` from `gplots` package.

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(t(sample_matrix_hist), 
      # turn off dendgrogram
      Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, dendrogram="none",
      # turn off density plot
      trace="none", density.info="none",
      # specify color palette
      col=rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"))(75)),
      ylab="", xlab="bins", key.xlab="frequency")
```

See `?heatmap.2` for details.

[image]

Finally, plotting histograms individually and facetted by columns in `ggplot2`.  Data needs to be reshaped first to long format.

```
# Reshape data to long format
library(reshape)
sample_matrix_hist_melt <- melt(sample_matrix_hist)

# Histogram is already pre-calculated, we only need to plot value of histogram so we use `geom_col`
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sample_matrix_hist_melt, aes(x=X1, y=value, fill=value)) + 
  geom_col(width=1) + facet_grid(X2~.) + theme_bw() + xlab("bin") + ylab("frequency") +
  scale_fill_distiller(type="div", palette="Spectral", direction=-1)
```

[image]

**Direct calculation and plotting of histograms: all in one!**

Alternatively, you can skip all this trouble and calculate histogram directly using `ggplot2` `geom_histogram` and color code by column.  This is why `ggplot2` is great!

```
library(reshape)
sample_matrix_melt <- melt(sample_matrix)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sample_matrix_melt, aes(x=value, fill=X2)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=hist_breaks) + 
  facet_grid(X2~.) + labs(fill="") +
  theme_bw() + xlab("bin") + ylab("frequency")
```

[image]

Observe that you cannot see values behind the high values in 3D plot, especially low counts which are evident in the `heatmap.2` and `ggplot2`.

Note: You can select the columns you want to plot simply by subsetting your original matrix.